# How can I access an SFTP server from a PODMAN container?

Tags: networking, podman

PODMAN Container access to a SFTP server

Hello Team,
I am new to PODMAN and container world.
I am running PODMAN on my mac pro .

I am able to access an IP from my mac pro
$ curl -v telnet://x.x.x.x:22

- Trying x.x.x.x:22...
- Connected to x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x) port 22 (#0)
  ^C
  --
  Now I am inside my container  and unable to connect to the same ip address
  curl -v telnet://x.x.x.x:22
- Rebuilt URL to: telnet://x.x.x.x:22/
- Trying x.x.x.x...
- TCP_NODELAY set
- connect to x.x.x.x port 22 failed: No route to host
- Failed to connect to x.x.x.x port 22: No route to host
- Closing connection 0
  curl: (7) Failed to connect to x.x.x.x port 22: No route to host

What do I need to do to have the access from my podman container

Answer (score 0):

When you run the container with the `podman run` command, are you enabling the output ports?

Such as:

```
podman run -p 3000:22 ... SFTP
```

If you do not specify an output port for the container, you will not be able to access it from the host.
I hope this helps.